# Setting link target through views programatically

Tags: navigation, views

I have a text field that turns its value into a link, provided it's an absolute link. For some reason, setting the target to blank is not working. Am I doing something wrong? I set the target inside the array.

```
elseif (valid_url($row->{$view->field['field_myDoc_link_value']->field_alias}, TRUE)) {
  $fields['title']->content = l(
    $fields['title']->content,
    $row->{$view->field['field_myDoc_link_value']->field_alias},
    array('target'=>'_blank', 'html' => TRUE)
  );
}
```

Or would I set it somewhere else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to define the target under attributes, so

```
array('target'=>'_blank', 'html' => TRUE)
```

should instead be:

```
array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'), 'html' => TRUE)
```